# How to change the style of an ng-select control when an option is selected

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-ngselect

I need to use the component [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) , but when I select an option in the control I got this blue outline in the select component :

[image]

I need to customize this to match the style in my other components.
I tried changing the outline property in the two classes that they mention in [the `Custom Styles` section](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#custom-styles), but nothing happens

Is there any way I can change the color and size of that blue outline? What class should I use?

### EDIT:

[STACKBLITZ - DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ll5zo-hqupeg)

Thanks

Comment: add your fiddle or stackblitz and code you try till now.

Comment: I just created a project in stackblitz that shows this outline I need to customize https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ll5zo-hqupeg

Comment: Added answer @eddy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add css to style.css

```
.ng-select.ng-select-focused:not(.ng-select-opened)>.ng-select-container {
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075), 0 0 0 3px rgba(0,126,255,0.1);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ll5zo-ko2nzx?file=src/styles.scss

[image]

Comment: Thanks aviboy2006 I was about to ask you how I could get rid of that blue outline and then I realized it was just a shadow. May I ask how you managed to find the exact selector?

Comment: I did inspect element on hover i check what is effect. Then copy style and edit in style.css.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're having issues with the component encapsulation. You can always try a few things, forcing the styles to change, such as:

- ::ng-deep or /deep/ (it'll be deprecated)
- :host-context
- `!important` (very bad practice)

Find more info in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Although you can achieve what you want with any of the options above, the library or plugin should allow you to modify the styles without extra configurations. Perhaps, if you share a working example (Stackblitz or some fiddle), I could understand better your problem.

Comment: No, I don't think so, because I'm not trying to change the style from within the component, but from the global styles.scss

Comment: You won't be able to access a child component from the global styles.scss because of encapsulation. That's why I'm trying to explain. Have a look at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

Comment: Nope, but I can set a global style that I can later use. I do that all the time with material components

Comment: I just added a demo in STACKBLITZ

Answer (score -1):

Display data using ng-option
If you have simple use case, you can omit items array and bind options directly in html using ng-option component.